# Como hacer consulta Sql en eloquent laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo una consulta en MySQl:

```
SELECT E.EXPE_varHR,E.EXPE_varDescripcion, 
T.TIPO_varDenominacion,T.TIPO_booSAP, (SELECT SUM(EXPE_intDiasTramite) 
FROM gen_expedientes EX INNER join gen_tipos TT on 
EX.TIPO_intId=TT.TIPO_intId WHERE EX.EXPE_varRaizHR=E.EXPE_varRaizHR and 
TT.TIPO_booSAP=1) as 'Sumado'
from gen_expedientes E INNER JOIN gen_tipos T ON 
E.TIPO_intId=T.TIPO_intId
```

y me gustaría saber como pasarla a eloquent, básicamente como hacer esa subconsulta

> ((SELECT SUM(EXPE_intDiasTramite) FROM gen_expedientes EX INNER join
>   gen_tipos TT on EX.TIPO_intId=TT.TIPO_intId WHERE
>   EX.EXPE_varRaizHR=E.EXPE_varRaizHR and TT.TIPO_booSAP=1) as 'Sumado')

en eloquent

Answer (score 2):

Si alguien tiene una duda similar, les dejo como lo solucione:
Use el DB::RAW

```
$ListaIngresos=\DB::table('gen_expedientes as E')
                      ->join('gen_tipos as T','E.TIPO_intId','=','T.TIPO_intId')
                      ->select('E.*','T.TIPO_varSiglas','T.TIPO_booSAP',
                        \DB::raw('(SELECT SUM(EXPE_intDiasTramite) FROM gen_expedientes EX INNER join gen_tipos TT on EX.TIPO_intId=TT.TIPO_intId WHERE EX.EXPE_varRaizHR=E.EXPE_varRaizHR and TT.TIPO_booSAP=1) as Sumado'))
                      ->get();
      return $ListaIngresos;
```

solo fue agregar.

> DB::raw('(SELECT SUM(EXPE_intDiasTramite) FROM gen_expedientes EX
>   INNER join gen_tipos TT on EX.TIPO_intId=TT.TIPO_intId WHERE
>   EX.EXPE_varRaizHR=E.EXPE_varRaizHR and TT.TIPO_booSAP=1) as Sumado')